# Setting Main nib for universal app in Info.plist?

Tags: ios, key, universal, info.plist

I am using the latest version of Xcode and my iDevices are 5.0.1. I am trying to specify the nib that the app should load depending if it is an iPad or iPhone for a universal app in my Info.plist but it seems that this is harder than I thought!

I thought we were supposed to use:
NSMainNibFile

But it seems that, that they key is no longer used!

Can someone tell me how I should do this instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Screw the Plist.  Open up a new project (single view) turn off arc, make it universal, then take a look at the app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method for your specific XIB if-then statement.

Comment: I don't want to make a new project, how would I do this with a already existing project?

Comment: Just copy and paste :P I wasn't implying you should start from scratch.  Rather, use the template as a codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get both when you create the project with `Universal` setting for device:

> File -> New -> New Project -> Empty Application -> set the **Device Family** to **Universal**.

---

If you want to set it base on your exist project:

1. Choose the project target(the blue one on the sidebar).
2. `Summary` -> `iOS Application Target` -> set `Devices` to `Universal`.

Comment: I don't want to make a new project, how would I do this with a already existing project?